# "Letting somebody down" and "bummer"

Tags: word-choice, vocabulary, slang

I know some informal words for disappointing people/doing something unpleasant to them, but I want to make sure that these sentences sound natural:

> "I don't believe our teacher is gonna give us an exam today! He wouldn't let us down!"
>
> "Our teacher wouldn't give us an exam today! That'd be a bummer!"
>
> "Did John (a friend we trusted) really do that to you? What a bummer/letdown!"

If they sound awkward, what other words could I use in these situations?

Comment: Seriously? You know how to use the (weird, imho) expression "**dick** move" in three different examples, but you don't recognise "**bad** move" as a non-profane alternative? Or maybe "**stupid** move" - I don't even know exactly what you want it to mean.

Comment: @FumbleFingers That's why I'm here: to learn. Thank you for your suggestions. In the last sentence, I meant that somebody made offensive cartoons of Bob. I find them stupid and think that they may hurt his feelings.

Comment: Perhaps for that specific context *an **idiotic** move* might be better. But then again it might be even better to forget about adjectivally modifying the word "move", since it's not really relevant to the context. *"That's puerile!"*, or *"That's childish!"* might have greater force, since they both rise well above the "playground swear-words" level of things like *"Dick move!"*

Comment: ...note that I have closevoted "Primarily Opinion-based" because you've obviously got at least two significantly different example contexts. If you want a context-specific alternative expression, you need to give us an exact context (is the "bad move" bad because it's stupid, inconsiderate, very undesirable for those affected, or what?).

Comment: "Bad move" doesn't actually mean the same as "dick move".  A "dick move" is a cruel, callous, unkind action - something that (probably deliberately) harms somebody.  A "bad move" is just "a mistake" - an ill-advised move, an unproductive move.  "Dick move" is about a move's effects on others.  "Bad move" is somewhat more about a move's effects on yourself.  If you're playing Chess, a "dick move" would be a move that hurts your opponent (though in Chess you're *supposed* to hurt your opponent).  A "bad move" would be one that hurts yourself.

Comment: @Stephen: I'm not saying you're *wrong* with that distinction, but I would take some convincing - especially about the idea that an ***attacking*** play in chess might be called a "dick move". I might even need convincing that people who use the term actually recognise good/bad moves in chess.

Comment: I've moved my question and sentences with "dick move" to [another question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/48236/alternatives-for-a-dick-move).

Comment: The chess example was a stretch, since "dick move" contains a certain disapproval that wouldn't be appropriate in chess.  Claiming that people who use the term wouldn't be knowledgeable about chess is rather elitist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could say something like "This really sucks" or "I'm very disappointed".

Comment: So the verb "to disappoint" is also used colloquially? In my native language, it sounds more formal.

Comment: Well it is slightly more formal but it would sound more normal than "he wont let us down" Does this help?