# Wanting to avoid vulgarity; alternatives for "a dick move"

Tags: vocabulary, slang

I have heard the slang phrase *dick move* in contexts like this:

> "Please don't do that prank to him. That'd be a *dick move* from you."
>
> "Look at those drawings of Bob! Do you know who made them? That's a *dick move*!"

I understand what the phrase means, but what other colloquial expressions could I use to replace the slang *dick move*? I want to avoid swear words and convey the same sentiment in a way that is would be regarded as more polite and less offensive.

Comment: "Dick move" is a common expression among young people in the United States, and I can't think of a synonym.  Simply substituting _rude, idiot, jerk or bad_ does not capture it.  You may not be able to find a good synonym, and instead have to resort to using an adjective.  ( _That was an obnoxious thing to do._ is the closest I can come. )

Comment: The first 8 definitions and sample sentences at The Urban Dictionary for [dick move](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=dick+move) are surprisngly on target and useful.

Comment: Try "That's LAME! ... Especially if it was both stupid and inappropriate. (Of course that's somewhat dated slang, having been more popular a couple of decades ago than now.)

Comment: "That's a lousy thing to do" comes close to expressing the same sentiment.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could say something along the lines of "that's a rude move".

Rude could stand in for Dick

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. Woud it sound natural if I said "That's rude!" after seeing offensive drawings made to mock someone? Does it express that I feel sorry for the boy on the drawing?

Comment: Yes it does! Hope this helps

Comment: Or jerk.  A jerk-move would be understood

Comment: **I didn't down-vote,** (votes = -1 at time of this comment) but "That's a rude move", sounds unnatural and (IMO) improperly conflates *rude* with *dick move*. Also, it's not accurate to equate *rude* with *dick*:  *`He is a dick.`* but not *`*He is a rude.`*  **Suggested Edits:**  You could change it to simply, "That's rude!" (That's what OP clarified in the comments and likely led to OP selecting this answer.)  So also, cull the additional context from user14197's comment directly into the answer.

Answer (score 10):

Saying something is *not cool* captures the same sentiment. It’s fairly flexible:

> Don’t prank him. That would *not* be *cool.*
>
> Don’t prank him. That’s *not cool.*

You could also tell someone not to be *that guy.*<sup>[[examples]](http://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/2e7i2p/what_are_some_that_guy_behaviors/)</sup>

> Don’t prank him. You don’t want to be *that guy.*

Comment: Those are euphemisms at best.

Comment: I don't understand your comment, @TrangOul.

Answer (score 2):

A very polite altemative would be "faux pas" (pronounced foe-paw). This is a French phrase adopted into English; it literally means "false step", but is used specifically to denote an act that is socially unacceptable, something that is just "not done in polite company".

Your rude friend might not get it, and think you're being hoity-toity or high-falutin, or he might get it, but still think you're prissy or a goody two-shoes. Go ahead and say it anyway—he'll get over it.

Comment: "Faux pas" sounds like something that one is entirely unconscious of, a social convention or rule of politeness that one is ignorant of - whereas "dick move" sounds like something which, a lot of the time, the person doing it is aware that they're doing it, and the rest of the time, others feel that they really ought to have been aware (whereas faux pas are often understandable because they tend to come from someone from a different culture or different social circle or educational background).

Answer (score 1):

`Dick moves` aren't just mean or inconsiderate, it's explicitly identifying something a person should be ashamed of. So focus on the shaming and less on the deed.

> Don't poop in his shoes, <strike>that's such a dick move.</strike>

`You're better than that.`

`Who does that?`

`Don't be a Schmuck`

Comment: Your answer is the only one so far that captures a critical element of "dick move".  The phrase combines an observation about the inappropriate nature of the action with a derogatory reference to a person who would do such a thing.  The "should be ashamed of" captures that.  One difference, though, is that "that's a dick move" doesn't directly insult the actor, it derides anyone in general who would do the action.  So, for example, "Only a schmuck would do that" would be closer than "Don't be a schmuck."

Comment: The word "schmuck" means the same thing as "dick" so is equally obscene to anyone who knows its meaning.

Answer (score 1):

"Egregious act" is a pretty good synonym IMO. It is the one I chose after coming to this page for alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this comes down to how you define the phrase in question. The Urban Dictionary lists two dozen meanings of the phrase; the one I'm using for this answer is #7 there:

> A socially unacceptable deed or act.

This one might be a little too sophisticated, depending on your audience, but there's the adjective **inappropriate**:

> Please don't do that prank to him. That would be *inappropriate*.

[Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/inappropriate#inappropriate_8) says the word is used for behavior that is "morally wrong or against acceptable social or professional standards," which seems like a good description of – ahem – a "bad move."

If you want something more slangy, there's the British term **not cricket**. A [UK Slang Dictionary](http://www.peevish.co.uk/slang/n.htm) defines the informal phrase as:

> Unacceptable or unfair behaviour : *I mean, it's just not cricket is it? Knowing that a meal contained beef fat and not telling a vegetarian until after they'd eaten it.*

[CDO](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/not-cricket) labels **not cricket** as `old-fashioned` or `humorous`, but their example sentence fits very well with the phrase you are asking about:

> *It's simply not cricket to flirt with another man's wife.*

The phrase *not cricket* isn't widely used in the U.S., but I've known the meaning of the phase for some time now, thanks to a song by the band Squeeze. We'd need a UK native to comment on its currency on the other side of the Atlantic, but at least it would be much more polite than the alternative you are asking about.

Comment: Your suggestions just don't come close to capturing the essence of "dick move".  To describe it with another vulgarity, "dick move" describes what an asshole would do.  The term combines the inappropriateness of the action with a derogatory reference to the person doing it.  Clinical terms or polite euphemisms like these  lack the second aspect.

Comment: @fixer - I agree my suggestions lack the shock value of the original expression. Your comment makes me wonder, though, if you noticed that the OP “wants to avoid swear words and convey the same sentiment in a way that is more polite and less offensive."

Comment: I saw that.  The point wasn't the shock value but the dual meaning.  Trevor Clarke's and Tyler James Young's answers somewhat capture that.  notpeter's answer explains it.

Comment: @fixer1234 - Okay, that’s fine. This is my least popular answer of almost 1500 given on ELL, but I’m going to keep it here. I’ve rehashed this over and over again in my head, and I still can’t really get why _inappropriate_ is so inappropriate. :-)

Comment: At least we're spending time discussion something of great social and political importance.

Comment: Things that are “inappropriate” are so because of the situation and wouldn’t be inappropriate in another situation. A dick move is always a dick move.

Answer (score 0):

As colloquial expressions, I would also suggest:

> That's ***a dirty/nasty trick***

or

> That's ***foul play***

I would also use

> That's ***a bad joke/ silly move***

or simply

> That's ***a stupid thing to do*** (the most colloquial of the expressions I have given)

See more on [PowerThesaurus](https://www.powerthesaurus.org/dick_move/synonyms)